# Run Update query in a migration in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration

I created the migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
}
```

I usually used this to creating tables or alter them . Is there a way to run an update query, something like:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `column` = 'test' WHERE `column` != 'test2';
```

and also the reverse of it. How can I do that?

Thank you!

[`UPDATE`] I followed this post: [Run raw SQL in migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787293/run-raw-sql-in-migration) , but there is no indication where should I add this update query or  how to **reverse** it . Its about just altering a table

Comment: @FMK srry but there is no indication where should i include that code and it is about altering tables , not updating , also there is no mention at all how to reverse  it . Thank you

Comment: @u_mulder , please see my update why it is not a duplicate . Thank you

Comment: Read __my__ duplicate, __please__. There're only __two__ places where you can put your code - `up` or `down` function. Thank you.

Comment: I managed to update it with `DB::statement("UPDATE `mytable` SET `column` = 'test' WHERE `column` != 'test2'");` . The `DB::raw` doesn't work  as suggested in the duplicates. But I still cannot find a way how to reverse it in the `down` method :(