# Is it possible to use sql query in Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an create table query as below

```
> CREATE TABLE ep_student (
>     student_id BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL,
>     stud_name CHARACTER(150)  NOT NULL,
>     no_kp CHARACTER(14)  NOT NULL,
>     dob DATE,
>     birth_place CHARACTER(100),
>     pob_desc CHARACTER(100),
>     dt_enroll DATE,
>     enroll_darjah CHARACTER(20),
>     religion_id CHARACTER(10),
>     ethnic_id CHARACTER(10),
>     citizenship_id CHARACTER(10),
>     warga_desc CHARACTER(100),
>     gender_id CHARACTER(10),
>     autisma_flag CHARACTER(10),
>     lelah_flag CHARACTER(10),
>     heart_flag CHARACTER(10),
>     skin_flag CHARACTER(10),
>     allergy_flag CHARACTER(10),
>     disability_flag CHARACTER(10),
>     disease_desc CHARACTER(100),
>     disability_desc CHARACTER(100),
>     dt_leftschool DATE,
>     reason_leftschool CHARACTER(100),
>     school_id BIGINT  NOT NULL,
>     birth_cert CHARACTER(20),
>     CONSTRAINT PK_ep_student PRIMARY KEY (student_id, no_kp, school_id)
```

Can I use DB::create in the Laravel Migration file and paste the scheme in it?

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run raw SQL in migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787293/run-raw-sql-in-migration)

Answer (score 3):

To execute query into migration you can use statement() method of DB class.

```
DB::statement("
    CREATE TABLE `your_table` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
");
```

Good Luck